# Exception NO_DATA_FOUND not setting variable value and DBMS_OUTOUT.PUT_LINE not showing as it should

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this weird behavior in a simple procedure I am trying to execute. The procedure just checks if some record is present in a table or not and and if the record is present then runs a procedure, if it is not then runs another procedure.  The procedure is like:

```
PROCEDURE p_checksomething (i_var1 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var2 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var3 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var4 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var5 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var6 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var7 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var8 VARCHAR2 
                ) 
IS 

v_var1 VARCHAR2(100); 
v_var2 VARCHAR2(100);  
v_var3 VARCHAR2(100);  
v_var4 VARCHAR2(100);  
v_var5 VARCHAR2(100); 
v_flag NUMBER := 0; 

BEGIN 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value1: '||v_flag); 


  SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5 
  INTO v_var1, v_var2, v_var3, v_var4, v_var5  
  FROM table1 a 
  WHERE a.col1 = 'i_var1' 
  AND a.col2 = 'i_var2' 
  AND a.col3 = 'i_var3' 
  AND a.col4 = 'i_var4' 
  AND a.col5 = 'i_var5'; 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value2: '||v_flag); 

  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
   v_flag := 1; 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE; 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value3: '||v_flag); 

IF v_flag = 1 THEN              /*INSERT INTO RU_INFO_T*/ 

 dbms_output.put_line('Flag value4: '||v_flag); 

package1.p_proc010(i_var1,i_var2,i_var3,i_var4,i_var5,i_var6,i_var7,i_var8); 

ELSE    IF v_flag = 0 THEN          /*UPDATE INTO RU_INFO_T*/ 

 dbms_output.put_line('Flag value5: '||v_flag); 
package1.p_proc100(i_var1,i_var2,i_var3,i_var4,i_var5,i_var6,i_var7,i_var8); 
END IF; 

END IF; 
dbms_output.put_line('Flag value6: '||v_insflag); 
END;
```

While it is compiling correctly but when I run it, the other two procedures are not running and on the console I can see only

`Flag value1: 0`

What is happening to the other dbms_output.put_line commands and why the variable is not changing in case of No Data Found is something I am dying with. It would be awesome if someone can think and give me some idea as to what I should do to get this flag value changed as I want.

Comment: So some other exception is thrown. Printing SQLERRM would help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to add begin-end block in order to handle exception.
You have only one EXCEPTION handler - and it is handler for procedure.
And when you catch exception, yes you initialise v_flag := 1 and then you exit from procedure;

```
PROCEDURE p_checksomething (i_var1 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var2 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var3 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var4 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var5 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var6 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var7 VARCHAR2, 
                            i_var8 VARCHAR2 
                ) 
IS 

v_var1 VARCHAR2(100); 
v_var2 VARCHAR2(100);  
v_var3 VARCHAR2(100);  
v_var4 VARCHAR2(100);  
v_var5 VARCHAR2(100); 
v_flag NUMBER := 0; 

BEGIN 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value1: '||v_flag); 

BEGIN   ---------------     new line  
  SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5 
  INTO v_var1, v_var2, v_var3, v_var4, v_var5  
  FROM table1 a 
  WHERE a.col1 = 'i_var1' 
  AND a.col2 = 'i_var2' 
  AND a.col3 = 'i_var3' 
  AND a.col4 = 'i_var4' 
  AND a.col5 = 'i_var5'; 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value2: '||v_flag); 

  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
   v_flag := 1; 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE; 
END;---------------           new line 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value3: '||v_flag); 

IF v_flag = 1 THEN              /*INSERT INTO RU_INFO_T*/ 

 dbms_output.put_line('Flag value4: '||v_flag); 

package1.p_proc010(i_var1,i_var2,i_var3,i_var4,i_var5,i_var6,i_var7,i_var8); 

ELSE    IF v_flag = 0 THEN          /*UPDATE INTO RU_INFO_T*/ 

 dbms_output.put_line('Flag value5: '||v_flag); 
package1.p_proc100(i_var1,i_var2,i_var3,i_var4,i_var5,i_var6,i_var7,i_var8); 
END IF; 

END IF; 
dbms_output.put_line('Flag value6: '||v_insflag); 
END;
```

Comment: I have another problem in the same query. The `SELECT INTO` is not setting the value as required in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that everything after `WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;` is still part of your `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler.  But it is all unreachable code.

If you want to have an exception handler in the middle of your code, you need to have a nested PL/SQL block (a `BEGIN`, an `EXCEPTION`, and an `END`).

```
BEGIN 

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value1: '||v_flag); 

  BEGIN
    SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5 
    INTO v_var1, v_var2, v_var3, v_var4, v_var5  
    FROM table1 a 
    WHERE a.col1 = 'i_var1' 
    AND a.col2 = 'i_var2' 
    AND a.col3 = 'i_var3' 
    AND a.col4 = 'i_var4' 
    AND a.col5 = 'i_var5'; 

    dbms_output.put_line('Flag value2: '||v_flag); 

  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
     v_flag := 1; 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE; 
  END;

  dbms_output.put_line('Flag value3: '||v_flag);
```

Of course, it really doesn't make sense to have a `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler that just re-raises the exception.  The best case is that you're throwing away the actual line that the error is coming from.  The `WHEN OTHERS` should be removed-- just let the exception propagate.

Depending on the Oracle version, [compiling with warnings](http://psoug.org/reference/plsql_warnings.html) would have raised a warning that everything after the `RAISE` was unreachable.  That may have pointed you in the direction of the solution to your problem.